# Cannot import numpy or matplotlib in Pycharm

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, ide, pycharm

So I have no clue why this is happening. I've installed all the dependencies through cmd using `python -m pi install -U (dependencies)` and in PyCharm's interpreter settings I have installed them as well and I can clearly see they are added to the project interpreter. But whenever I try and import them into my code, I get an 'unused import statement error' with the code being greyed out.

The files are definitely there. I've tried re-installing them a second time and CMD confirms that they are already installed.

I am using the latest PyCharm build (non beta) JetBrains PyCharm Community Edition 2018.2.4 x64. And Python 3.7. My installation directory is C:\Python 3.7\ and in site-packages directory I can clearly see the files in there.

Simple Motion Detection Program (without imported dependencies implemented into code):

```
from __future__ import division
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import cos, sin

first_frame = None

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

a = 1

while True:
    a = a + 1

    check, frame = video.read()
    print(frame)

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (21, 21), 0)

    if first_frame is None:
        first_frame = gray
        continue

    delta_frame = cv2.absdiff(first_frame, gray)

    thresh_delta = cv2.threshold(delta_frame, 40, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

    erode = cv2.erode(thresh_delta, None, iterations=1)

    dilate = cv2.dilate(erode, None, iterations=1)

    (_, cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(dilate.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for contour in cnts:
        if cv2.contourArea(contour) < 200:
            continue

        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow('captureFrame', frame)
    cv2.imshow('captureGrey', gray)
    cv2.imshow('delta', delta_frame)
    cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh_delta)
    cv2.imshow('dilate', dilate)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if key == ord('q'):
        break

print(a)
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: interpriter]

[image: error]

[image: site-packages]

Comment: Which code are you running and what exactly is the *complete*  error message?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Updated. With code and pictures..

Comment: There is no error. PyCharm just informs you about the fact that you have imported something without actually using it. This means you may just delete the grey lines, without them affecting the code.

Comment: wow... that's frustrating. I see what you mean now as soon as I throw in another line of code. While I understand it's smart to take out redundancies, this one really threw me off.. I know I can't be the only one.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest That pretty much answers it. I am still new to stackoverflow however. Is there a way to use a comment as an answer to the question so it can be archived?

Comment: No there isn't. You could rephrase your question to rather ask for the meaning of the tooltip you're seeing (instead of some error), and then you can answer it yourself if you want.